# Adding Missing Dates with 0 in Quantity in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time-series

I have a data frame that consist of a number of different item numbers from different locations. The problem is that I am missing dates for all the different combos.  So for example for item number 1, I want all the dates that are missing for all the locations.  What is the best way to add dates with quantity 0 for every single item at every single location for days that don't exist in the data set? Please and thank you!

[image]

I tried the following

```
df.set_index(data["DATE", "ITEMNUMBER"], inplace=True)

df = data.resample('D').sum().fillna(0)
```

Which gives me the following error - ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 1 rows, received array of length 749629

So I tried the following -

```
df.set_index(data["DATE", "ITEMNUMBER"], inplace=True)

df = data.resample('D').sum().fillna(0)
```

That results in a Key Error  if tolerance is not None:

Comment: post data as text, or better, share sample data as code : ``df.to_dict('records')``. .Also, post the expected output dataframe, as code, if possible, or text

Comment: Reindex your data with a date index. Then fill na with 0.

Comment: Can you try if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68567786/16343464) matches your need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all combinations of `DATE`, `ITEMNUMBER`, and `LOCATION` you can try:

```
import itertools
df2 = df.set_index(["DATE", "ITEMNUMBER", "LOCATION"])
df2 = df2.reindex(itertools.product(df['DATE'].unique(),
                                    df['ITEMNUMBER'].unique(),
                                    df['LOCATION'].unique())
                 ).fillna(0).reset_index()
df2
```

example input:

```
         DATE  ITEMNUMBER LOCATION  QUANTITY
0  2021-07-28           1        A         0
1  2021-07-28           2        B         1
2  2021-07-28           1        B         2
3  2021-07-29           1        A         3
4  2021-07-30           2        A         4
```

output:

```
          DATE  ITEMNUMBER LOCATION  QUANTITY
0   2021-07-28           1        A       0.0
1   2021-07-28           1        B       2.0
2   2021-07-28           2        A       0.0
3   2021-07-28           2        B       1.0
4   2021-07-29           1        A       3.0
5   2021-07-29           1        B       0.0
6   2021-07-29           2        A       0.0
7   2021-07-29           2        B       0.0
8   2021-07-30           1        A       0.0
9   2021-07-30           1        B       0.0
10  2021-07-30           2        A       4.0
11  2021-07-30           2        B       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a toy data frame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': '2014-07-14', 'id': 1, 'q': 1}, {'date': '2014-07-15', 'id': 1, 'q': 1}, {'date': '2014-07-17', 'id': 1, 'q': 1}, {'date': '2014-07-18', 'id': 1, 'q': 2}, {'date': '2014-07-14', 'id': 5, 'q': 2}])
>>> df
         date  id  q
0  2014-07-14   1  1
1  2014-07-15   1  1
2  2014-07-17   1  1
3  2014-07-18   1  2
4  2014-07-14   5  2
```

I convert the dates to date times, then within each ID, reindex between the index minimum and maximum, creating empty rows. I then fill the quantity column `q` with 0 for `np.nan` and forward fill remaining nulls.

```
>>> df.assign(date=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df['date'])) \
    .set_index('date').groupby('id') \
    .apply(lambda df: df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='D'))) \
    .assign(q=lambda df: df['q'].fillna(0)). \
    .groupby(level=0).ffill()
                id    q
id                     
1  2014-07-14  1.0  1.0
   2014-07-15  1.0  1.0
   2014-07-16  1.0  0.0
   2014-07-17  1.0  1.0
   2014-07-18  1.0  2.0
5  2014-07-14  5.0  2.0
```

I'm not sure how you want to deal with the location column. My answer is simplified by removing that column entirely.

If you don't yourself know, **do not `ffill` at the end**. Instead, group by and assign an `ffill` *of the ID column only* back to ID, leaving the location as `nan`.

Comment: Thanks @ifly6 but I do admit I need the location so I need it for location, date, and item number.

Comment: @westiegirl there is no location data that can be robustly forward filled. you need to tell me how you intend to impute something like a delivery location for something that was never ordered.

Comment: valid point. I figured it out. Thanks for your help.